# Do any other episodes of The Big Bang Theory mention The Princess Bride when Kripke is present?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory, the-princess-bride

In last night's episode of *The Big Bang Theory* ("The Perspiration Implementation", S09E05), Wolowitz and Koothrappali each quote a line from *The Princess Bride.*

> Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die.

This occurs during fencing lessons conducted by Kripke.

Are there any other episodes featuring Kripke which also include a reference to *The Princess Bride*?

Kripke and some of the characters in The Princess Bride have speech impediments. I was curious whether this connection might be recurrent.

Comment: It's arguably one of the most famous lines prior to a sword fight, so I doubt it had any particular link to Kripke. *How I Met Your Mother* also used it in scenes where they were messing around with swords.

Answer (score 4):

Raj referenced "The Prince Bride" in the episode The Workplace Proxemity (S7E5). In this episode, Raj tells Leonard that he and Howard were eating cookie dough while watching The Princess Bride.
These are the only two references of "The Prince Bride" in TBBT and I assume that they have nothing to do with Kripke’s speech impediments, because Kripke pretends to be ["Inigo Montoya" who has just a Spanish accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3W5GDkgf2w).                  [The Impressive Clergyman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bY0fdgpISc) looks and sounds a bit like Kripke but to draw here a connection to the The Big Bang Theory character is a bit too far away.